Optimal buffer size for writing to disk while extracting ZIP files
I'm writing an unzip function for my Kotlin app and in order to report progress, I will be doing it without copyTo but via a buffer. The examples I find always use a buffer of 1024 bytes. Are there any particular reasons to keep it this size or would it be advisable to use a smaller or a larger one in certain situations?

Update: I wasn't aware of multiple buffers being used. One for extraction and one for writing. The one I mean in this question is the write buffer. Here is my code:
        fun ZipEntry.extract(zipFile: ZipFile, newFile: File, progress: (BytesWritten) -> Unit) : BytesUnzipped {
            var bytesUnzipped = 0L
            zipFile.getInputStream(this).use { input ->
                newFile.outputStream().use { output ->
                    val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
                    var bytesRead: Int
                    while (input.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } > 0) {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                        bytesUnzipped += bytesRead
                        progress(BytesWritten(bytesRead))
                    }
                }
            }
            return BytesUnzipped(bytesUnzipped)
        }

@JvmInline
value class BytesWritten(val value: Int)

@JvmInline
value class BytesUnzipped(val value: Long)


There probably isn't an optimal value for all cases (big files vs small files, highly compressible vs non-compressible, embedded devices vs desktop computers). I would recommend keeping it a power of 2. Try it for your use cases and see.

@ElliottFrisch does this mean that zipper-apps like 7zip or Windows itself pick the buffer size dynamically based on the filesize or other criteria?

@ElliottFrisch I've found the default for copyTo in Kotlin's source code. It's 8k. libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/io/Constants.kt

They probably just pick a value and call it good enough. 8192 seems reasonable. It's probably not going to make a big difference. Most operating systems use buffered io these days, so you're reading from one buffer to fill another buffer (in reality).

Are you talking about buffer for reading or writing? For the latter a buffer is really important. But 1k is very small. Filesystems usually use 4k sectors. On disk level SSD use much larger blocks so using a large buffer may improve writing speed.

To generalize @Robert’s comment, we don’t have enough information about your use case. If, for example, the source is a ZipInputStream, the decompression specific buffering will be handled by the source. So the size choice for your buffer would only depend on the target. As Robert said, it might be too small for today’s local filesystems. But we don’t know what you’re doing.

@Holger you're right! I hadn't thought there was another buffer for extraction. I clarified that in my question and added an example of my cude. I mean the buffer for writing.
